# Possibility of programmatically controlling speakers individually in an Android device?

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager

I have a Nexus 5 and want to **develop an app to control the speakers in the phone separately.** 
I know that the nexus-5 has just one speaker at the bottom. But there small speaker that we use during calls, I wish to use that too. I looked through the android developer website, but couldn't find any information on how to access the speakers separately.

***Is there a way to access the speaker used during calls (one on the top) separately and the one used during loudspeaker (one at the bottom) individually ?***

I am not sure if this is even possible. Any suggestion is a good direction would be good for this.